# Rails 3.1 Authlogic NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, authlogic

I'm currently trying to get authlogic working with my Rails 3.1 installation.  In my Gemfile I have: `gem 'authlogic'`

running bundle install works perfectly, but in my app/models/user_session.rb file (shown below), I get this error:

> uninitialized constant AuthLogic (NameError)

user_session.rb:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
end
```

Am I simply forgetting to require something?  I've searched all over and haven't been be able to come up with anything.  I'd be happy to provide more information if needed.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere you've referenced the constant `AuthLogic`, when you should have referenced `Authlogic`. Lower-case L.

Comment: oh. my. god.  Perfect example of why you should step away when you've been at it for hours.  thank you

Comment: @FuZion: if this did fix your question please click the checkmark underneath it.